# Power series expression for $\exp(-\Delta)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, power-series, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

I know it should be true, but for some reason I can't get the calculations to work out in order to show that if $f$ is smooth and compactly supported, the power series 
$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(\partial_x^2)^j}{j!} f $ converges in $L^2$.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: -Do you mean $\exp(\Delta)$ in the title?  As DavidC.Ullrich noticed, that doesn't seem to match with your power series $(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(\partial_x^2)^j}{j!})$ (or is yours the negative of the usual Laplacian).

Answer (score 4):

This a potential answer to the question.  It is not clear whether its proof technique can be completed or not.

---

We can obtain the result by considering convergence of the Fourier transform of the partial sums.  Since $f$ is smooth and compactly supported it is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as are all of its derivatives.

Let $f_n$ be the $n$th partial sum in the series: $f_n = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(\partial_x^2)^j}{j!} f$.  We can compute the Fourier transform of $f_n$ as:
$$\mathcal{F}(f_n)(k) = \mathcal{F}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(\partial_x^2)^j}{j!} f\right)(k) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(2\pi i k)^{2j}}{j!} \hat{f}(k) = \hat{f}(k) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-4\pi^2 k^2)^j}{j!}$$

Therefore (quesionably, see below) $\hat{f}_n \to \hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Then by Plancherel's theorem, $f_n \to \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2})$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

---

### Update:

> $\hat{f}_n \to \hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

There seems to be some disagreement over whether this statement is true so I'll add details (and am unable to complete the proof).  As demonstrated above,
 $$\hat{f}_n(k) = \hat{f}(k) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-4\pi^2 k^2)^j}{j!}$$
Observe that $\hat{f}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by Plancharel's theorem.  Likewise, $\hat{f}(k)e^{-4\pi^2 k^2}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (because $e^x \leq 1$ for all $x \leq 0$).

We want to show that 
$$||\hat{f}(k)e^{-4\pi^2 k^2} - \hat{f}_n(k)||_2 \to 0$$
i.e. for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$
$$||\hat{f}(k) \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-4\pi^2 k^2)^j}{j!}||_2 \leq \epsilon$$

To that end, we use the bound for alternating series that $|\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_j| \leq |a_{n+1}|$.  Hence,
$$|\hat{f}(k) \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-4\pi^2 k^2)^j}{j!}| \leq |\hat{f}(k)| \frac{(4\pi^2 k^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

It is well known that if a function $f$ is smooth then its fourier transform satisfies 
$$|\hat{f}(k)| \leq \frac{C_m}{k^m}$$
for all $m > 0$ (see e.g. [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206362/smoothness-and-decay-property-of-fourier-transformation)).  Using this estimate we can make the tail of the series arbitrarily small.
$$\int_T^\infty |\hat{f}(k)|^2 \left|\frac{(4\pi^2 k^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right|^2 dk \leq 
C_m^2 \int_T^\infty \left|\frac{(4\pi^2)^{2n+2} (k^{2n + 2 - 2m})}{(n+1)!}\right| dk$$

(This is the false step as is:)  Using this, we can choose $N, T$ sufficiently large that
$$\int_T^\infty |\hat{f}(k)|^2 \left|\frac{(4\pi^2 k^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right|^2 dk \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$
for all $n \geq N$.

To finish the proof, we choose $N_1, T$ so that $\forall n \geq N_1$:
$$||(\hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2} - \hat{f}_n)\chi_{[-T, T]}||_2 < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Using this and the bounds for the tail of the integral establish above we can show there exists $N_2 \geq N_1$ such that for all $n \geq N_2$
$$||\hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2} - \hat{f}_n||_2 \leq \epsilon$$

---

I have asked the community for assistance with this at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398192/for-f-in-c-c-infty-mathbbr-does-hatfk-sum-j-0n-frac-k2j).

Comment: Excellent proof! +1

Comment: One of us is missing something. I don't see what that sum has to so with $\exp(-\Delta)$ in the first place! In one variable: $\exp(-\Delta)=\sum(-\partial_x^2)^j/j!$; now on the Fourier transform side this becomes $F(\exp(-\Delta)f)(k)=e^{k^2}\hat f(k),$ not $e^{-k^2}$. ???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - That's a good point!  Maybe the OP miswrote the title.  His question asks about $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(\partial_x^2)^j}{j!} f $ converges in $L^2$ so I'll work with that.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be true because every term in the series has the same compact support. Since this is a solution to the heat equation, it should spread out.

Edit: Another way of looking at this follows from the ["uncertainty principle" : the Fourier transform of a "bump function" cannot decay exponentially fast](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138302/compactly-supported-function-whose-fourier-transform-decays-exponentially).
Thus we expect $||(\frac {d}{dx})^n f|| = ||k^n \tilde f||$ to grow more rapidly than $\int{_0 ^\infty}k^n e^{-kx}dx \approx n! . $

Yet another way is that the "bump functions" are not a domain of essential self-adjointness. This is explained in the case of the operator $i\frac{d}{dx}$ on pp. 97-98 of [An Introduction to the Mathematical Structure of Quantum Mechanics](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Bn7MaT3X8fkC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=exponential++id/dx#v=onepage&q=exponential%20%20id%2Fdx&f=false).

Comment: In Answer #1 I question this step: "Therefore $\hat{f}_n \to \hat{f}e^{-4\pi^2 k^2}$ ...". This would hold if the remainder of the series converged uniformly to zero (as a function of $k$), but I don't think it is true in general.

Comment: $|| f_n - f_{n-1} ||^2$ is like $\int k^{4n} |f(k)|^2 dk / (n!)^2$. There are limitations on how slowly Fourier transforms of "bump functions" can drop off. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138302/compactly-supported-function-whose-fourier-transform-decays-exponentially

Comment: Are you sure about this? As far as i can see, the $n$'th partial sum is perfectly well-defined in the time domain, and the limit is well-defined in the frequency domain (as it is merely an exponential).

Comment: The "Therefore ..." would work if $\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-4\pi^2 k^2)^j}{j!}$ converged uniformly to $e^{-4\pi^2 k^2}$ but it is far from uniform. There is classical theory relating to the Question: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quasi-analytic_class

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I have to use the solution i ended up with which is $H_0=-\Delta$ that we see that as $F(H_0 f)=\xi^2Ff$ we have that $F^{-1}\exp(-t\xi^2)Ff=\exp(-tH_0)f$ by the unbounded functional calculus, since $\exp(-x)$ is bounded on the spectrum of $H_0$. Therefore we may calculate for $t\geq 0$, and $f\in C_c^{\infty}$. 
$(\exp(-tH_0)f)(x)=F^{-1}\exp(-t\xi^2)Ff$
$F^{-1} ( \exp(-t\xi) \hat{f})$
$\frac{1}{(2\pi t)^m}\exp(-\frac{-x^2}{2t})*f(y)$
 which is what we desired. We may extend this to the entirety of $L^2$ via. standard methods of approximating $L^2$ functions

Comment: $C^2 \int_T^\infty \left|\frac{(4\pi^2)^{2n+2} (k^{2n + 2 - 2m})}{(n+1)!}\right| dk$ diverges for n>m.

Comment: $|\hat{f}(k)| \leq \frac{C}{k^m}$ for all $m > 0$ implies that $\hat{f}(k)= 0$ for $k>1$. I think $C$ must be a function of $m$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary  (+1) You are right, $C$ does depend on $m$.